# Visual Studio 2019 say dtproj SSIS project is unsupported

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to open my dtproj SSIS project in Visual Studio 2019 and it says its unsupported and incompatible.  What am I missing?  I installed VS with SSDT so it should work.  I compared the about-info of both and found the VS that didn't work lacked the following.  Is SSIS 15 a separate install?  If so, where do I get it?

Snapshot Debugging Extension 1.0
Snapshot Debugging Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Integration Services 15.0.2000.180
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 15.0.2000.180

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019 00435-60000-00000-AA131
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019

Comment: Have you installed the SSIS extension in Visual Studio? SSDT is just for database projects.

Comment: not at first, but I have it installed now and when I open my ssis dtproj it says "the 'global hub client package' package did not load correctly." it says I should restart VS.

Comment: restarting didn't work.  it still says unsupported over the project.

Answer (score 0):

@larnu has part of the answer, that is, install the SSIS extension.  After doing that it still won't work (or didn't in my case).  The project still said 'unsupported' and I right clicked it in solution explorer and clicked 'reload project' and after that the project loaded correctly.

Comment: now I can't publish...it says a Integration Services catalog SSISDB was not found on this server instance.  Open the create catalog dialog box from the integration services catalog node.

Comment: what part of that message is unclear? Not only must SSIS must be installed in the server, the SSIS catalog database needs to be created.

Comment: its clear, but it can't be done because something is weird. The 'integration services' is missing from my installation media for sql server.  I downloaded the SQL server 2019 dev edition and its just not there.  Have they removed this feature from the developer edition?

Comment: Installation services is a shared component of the Developer Edition. Are you sure you have Developer rather than Express?

Comment: I think I have both installed, but I'm using the installer for the express edition or something like that

Comment: I double checked and it is definitely the developer edition that I downloaded and installed.  I reinstalled and Integration Services is missing from the feature selection page.  Might this be by M$ design?

Comment: Actually it was the express edition, I had accidentally installed it.  However, now I'm back to the unsupported 'this version of visual studio is unable to open' error